# Relative importance and p value of a model

Tags: r, regression, self-study, p-value, importance

I am trying to understand relative importance and have come across the relaimpo package for R. In it they run an lm model on the swiss data set. The results indicate that examination is insignificant based on the p-value.

```
 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 66.91518 10.70604 6.250 1.91e-07 ***
Agriculture -0.17211 0.07030 -2.448 0.01873 *
Examination -0.25801 0.25388 -1.016 0.31546
Education -0.87094 0.18303 -4.758 2.43e-05 ***
Catholic 0.10412 0.03526 2.953 0.00519 **
Infant.Mortality 1.07705 0.38172 2.822 0.00734 **
---
Signif. codes: 0 ’***’ 0.001 ’**’ 0.01 ’*’ 0.05 ’.’ 0.1 ’ ’ 1
Residual standard error: 7.165 on 41 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.7067, Adjusted R-squared: 0.671
F-statistic: 19.76 on 5 and 41 DF, p-value: 5.594e-10
```

They then run a simple relative importance metric on the data set using the first metric, which is described as a comparison of what each regressor alone is able to explain resulting in examination being the second highest variable.

```
metrics$first
Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
0.1246649 0.4171645 0.4406156 0.2150035 0.1735189
```

My question is how do I interpret this? Based on the p-value this variable is insignificant but conducting relative importance its the 2nd highest? Should examination not have been used in the lm model? Should the p value ever be used for feature selection?

Link to paper:
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6305006.pdf

Comment: In order to answer this someone is going to have to download her package (assuming relaimp is a typo for relaimpo) and install it or at least download the paper (which you do not reference), read what the "first metric" is, and then answer. Please edit your question to include the key details of the methods used so that it is self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aforementioned package offers six different tests for relative importance of coefficients. The method you used, `first`, is calculated as the *univariate* $R^2$ for each covariate. This is of course a poor way of comparing relative importance of coefficients in multiple regression models, unless all covariate snare truly independent of each other.

In this case, they are clearly not. $p$ values are important. They tell us whether a coefficient has a large enough effect to satisfactorily allow us to reject $H_0$, while controlling for all other independent variables. Controlling means that some other variables can be shown as interfering with the relationship. Here, while a univariate model would show a strong relationship between `examination` and the dependent variable, controlling other variables show that the actual relationship is much weaker (given that there are no problems with the model).

Comment: am i correct in saying then that the metric first should be used when there is no correlation between the independent variables?

Comment: Yes. But I mean, NO correlation. I don't really understand to point of this type of comparison really, because even with uncorrelated variables a comparison of, say, standardized values, would work just fine.